# Android studio refuses to put views inside custom container

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I know there is silly mistake somewhere but I can't figure out where.
I got following container's code:

```
public class ImagesView extends LinearLayout {
public ImagesView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public ImagesView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    float ar=(float)896/768;
    this.setMeasuredDimension(widthSize, (int) (widthSize/5*(1f/ar)));
    //this.setMeasuredDimension(1280,240);
}
}
```

Layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.rhyboo.net.test.ImagesView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light">

<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</com.rhyboo.net.test.ImagesView>
```

In android studio I can see size of my container is set correctly, but if I add something into container it displays child views as zero-sized:
[image: zero-sized child view]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you please provide the full layout code?

Comment: yeah edited my initial post.Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your onMeasure does not call super.onMeasure... so chilren are never measured. Also when calling parents onMeasure you probably want to set mode to EXACTLY for width and/or height.

Comment: Yeah thanks that was a case.BTW how do I set mode on a container?

Comment: oh its MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec.Thanks again!